# Bootstrap Table width fills screen - thymeleaf/springboot

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap in my html thymeleaf template as follows:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  rel="stylesheet" 
  integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-striped table-sm" >
        <thead>
            <th>delete</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Consult Date</th>
            <th>Reservation Number</th>
            <th>dispense details</th>
```

The  table is stretched the width of my screen. How do I make table use 50-60% of the screen width?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize the [BS grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/) and place the table inside a column. There are 12 columns in the grid so for 50-60% of the screen width use `.col-6` (6/12 = 50%), `.col-7` (7/12 = 58.333%) or one of their responsive variants.

In the following example, I use `.col-sm-7` so it will take up all 12 columns on extra small screens and then only 7 columns on small and larger screens.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7">

      <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>delete</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Consult Date</th>
            <th>Reservation Number</th>
            <th>dispense details</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>yup</td>
            <td>yup</td>
            <td>yup</td>
            <td>yup</td>
            <td>yup</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>yup</td>
            <td>yup</td>
            <td>yup</td>
            <td>yup</td>
            <td>yup</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>yup</td>
            <td>yup</td>
            <td>yup</td>
            <td>yup</td>
            <td>yup</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```